# get repeated value from parent array and not repeated value from parent array

Tags: php, arrays, filter, unique, array-filter

one is parent array and another is filtered array.
From there i just want to set two seperate array 
common array
unique array

```
$a = array([0]=> Array
    (
        [id] => 22429
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ),[1]=> Array
    (
        [id] => 22430
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ),[2]=> => Array
    (
        [id] => 22431
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ),[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 22432
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ));

$b = array("0"=> Array
    (
        [id] => 22428
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ),"1" => Array
    (
        [id] => 22430
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ),[2]=> Array
    (
        [id] => 22431
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ),[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 22432
        [user_id] => 0
        [shop_id] => 78
        [start_date] =>
        [fn_point] => 0
    ));;
```

output for unique array will be

```
$c = array(
        [0]=> Array
        (
            [id] => 22429
            [user_id] => 0
            [shop_id] => 78
            [start_date] =>
            [fn_point] => 0
        )
    );
```

output for common array will be

```
$u = array(
        [0]=> Array
        (
            [id] => 22430
            [user_id] => 0
            [shop_id] => 78
            [start_date] =>
            [fn_point] => 0
        ),[1]=> Array
        (
            [id] => 22431
            [user_id] => 0
            [shop_id] => 78
            [start_date] =>
            [fn_point] => 0
        ),[2]=> Array
        (
            [id] => 22432
            [user_id] => 0
            [shop_id] => 78
            [start_date] =>
            [fn_point] => 0
        )
    );
```

Comment: `array_diff`, `array_intersect`.

Comment: Why are these numbers strings, and not integers?

Comment: @NilsWerner why does it matter? It could be a Json file that is decoded.

Comment: When you ask a question make sure what you ask is relevant to the actual code and variables. Single dimensional and multi dimensional arrays are handles completely different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get common from both array,use [array_intersect()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
$c = array_values(array_intersect($a,$b)); //array_values() used for re-indexing final array
print_r($c);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/1055829

Use [array_diff()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$c = array_values(array_diff($a,$b));//array_values() used for re-indexing final array
print_r($c);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/1055830

Reference:-

[array_values()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

***For your edited question*** apply `foreach()` along with `in_array()` and `array_column()`

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($a as $key=>$val){
  if(in_array($val['id'],array_column($b,'id'))){
    $final_array[] = $val;
  }

}

print_r($final_array); // common values array
```

Output:- https://eval.in/1055838

And

```
$final_array = [];

foreach($a as $key=>$val){
  if(!in_array($val['id'],array_column($b,'id'))){
    $final_array[] = $val;
  }

}

print_r($final_array); // non common value array
```

Output:-https://eval.in/1055839

Answer (score 1):

For your common array:

```
array_intersect($a, $b);
```

For your unique array:

```
array_unique(array_merge($a, $b), SORT_REGULAR);
```

Comment: I have updated my question. can u pls check it. array_unique not supporting.

Answer (score 1):

[Array_intersect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) and [array_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)

```
$a = array('1','2','3','4');
$b = array('4','5','6','7');

$c = array_intersect($a, $b);
var_dump($c); //4

$d = array_diff($a,$b);
var_dump($d); //1,2,3
```

https://3v4l.org/Ut8JW

Comment: I have updated my question. can u pls check it. \PhpErrorException: Array to string conversion